# Is using Assembly.Load a static reference or dynamic reference?

Tags: c#, assembly-loading

What are the implications and suggested scenarios to use either?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Assembly.Load` is a dynamic reference since you're dynamically loading an external DLL at run-time. You would consider a static reference more like when you're adding a reference to a .NET project and building the project with that reference in place.

EDIT:

From the MSDN Doc:

> The compiler records static references
>   in the assembly manifest's metadata at
>   build time.

Hmmm, not sure about this one myself. I'll keep my answer here for now, in the hope of getting more correction comments or seeing better answers.

Comment: This is not entirely correct I believe...a dyanamic reference as stated in the MSDN(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(VS.71).aspx) references dynamic referencing as loading a reference with only enough information that the runtime has to search for the assembly being loaded. With static references, the location of assemblies(GAC, application direcotry, etc) are known and can be still accomplished using Assembly.load.

Answer (score 2):

In reference to:

> What are the implications and
>   suggested scenarios to use either?

Usually, if I use `Assembly.Load()`, it is because I am developing a pluggable system. Dynamic references facilitate inclusion of assemblies that are not necessarily part of my build.

Instantiating types from a dynamically loaded assembly requires at least some reflection. The amount of reflection necessary can be mitigated by ensuring that dynamically-loaded types implement some known interface or base class (from a statically-loaded assembly).

In short, it's a lot of work to use dynamically loaded assemblies; however, doing so can make an application more flexible by allowing users to develop plug-ins. Just weigh the trade-offs of the anticipated flexibility of dynamic references (which may not be a requirement), and design-time support from Visual Studio for static references.

A practice worth consideration if building a plug-in architecture is to load assemblies in their own AppDomains. Doing so permits you to have finer-grained control over the security permissions of assemblies you may not entirely trust, and provides the added benefit that the assemblies can be unloaded at run-time. Personally, I found working with AppDomains to be labor-intensive; however, if the benefits are required, it's good to know that AppDomains are there.

Answer (score 0):

A dyanamic reference as stated in the MSDN(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(VS.71).aspx) references dynamic referencing as loading a reference with only enough information that the runtime has to search for the assembly being loaded.  With static references, the location of assemblies(GAC, application direcotry, etc) are known and can be still accomplished using Assembly.load.